# Add NSIS firewall exception for both private and public profiles

Tags: nsis, windows-firewall

I want to add my application to windows firewall excpetion list.
I am using [NSIS Simple Firewall Plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Firewall_Plugin) and doing following.

```
SimpleFC::AddApplication "${PRODUCT_NAME}" "$INSTDIR/${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" 3 2 "" 1
Pop $0 ; return error(1)/success(0)
```

My app is getting added successfully to the firewall exception list but the problem is I want to add the exception for both public and private network profiles like below:
[image]

But there is no option for same in the mentioned plugin, and the currently active profile (either public or private) gets selected by default.

I have explored other nsis firewall plugins but none of them has this feature. Can someone tell me the way forward? I may consider writing a custom plugin for the same.

But I am just wondering, is it achievabe or is there any fundamental blocker?

Although, you can always select both checkboxes manually.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was never able to get any of the NSIS Firewall plugins to work correctly for me. 
I ended up simply shelling out to netsh on my target system:

In the install section:

```
ExecWait 'netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=MyProg dir=in action=allow program="$INSTDIR\MyProg.exe" enable=yes profile=public,private'
```

In the uninstall section:

```
ExecWait 'netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=MyProg'
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to do the same.  SimpleFC would only add to public networks on Win8/10.

Comment: Use `nsExec::Exec` instead of `ExecWait` to avoid opening the dos window

Comment: @filippo - this didn't work for me; only `ExecWait` worked.  Perhaps something needs to be installed on the target machine beforehand?

Comment: To clarify the **uninstall** section: there is a missing `dir=in` at the end.  The whole command is `ExecWait 'netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=MyProg' dir=in`.  Also note that you need double-quotes around the arguments if they contain a space; e.g. `rule name="my rule name"`.

Comment: @EdGraham - Why do you say the dir=in is required on the uninstall? I just re-tested an installer I built without dir=in on the uninstall and it deleted the rule just fine. Is there some condition where that won't work?

Comment: @EdGraham - also, I checked and our code is using nsExec::ExecToLog at the moment. Not sure how I arrived there, but that's what's working for us at the moment.

Comment: @MichaelKohne - I tested your answer on a Windows 10 laptop last week (as admin) and the rule wasn't deleted unless I added the `dir=in` at the end.  I presumed this was because Windows didn't want to delete the wrong rule in the event that I might have both an Out and an In rule with the same name, although when I tested it I had no Out rules with that name.

Comment: @EdGraham - absolutely fascinating. I wonder what's different on my end that it works for me? dir=in is clearly more correct, but can't fathom why it works for me without that, but not for you.

Comment: @MichaelKohne - I was using a freshly installed laptop with just Windows and very little software besides .NET (for testing purposes); so my guess is that something important is installed on yours and not on mine.  This might explain why `nsExec::*` doesn't work for me either (whereas it does for you and @filippo).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling SimpleFC::AdvAddRule? Set the profile parameter to a value from [NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366303(v=vs.85).aspx). You could try 0x7FFFFFFF but the plugin you are using is written in Pascal and I don't know if it supports hex so you might have to fall back to 2147483647.

Comment: I tried it , but it doesn't lists my app in the firewall exception's list. Doing following :-
`SimpleFC::AdvAddRule "${PRODUCT_NAME}" "${PRODUCT_NAME}" 256 2 1 2147483647 1 "$INSTDIR/${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""`

Answer (score 0):

For SimpleFC use this function with profile=6:

```
SimpleFC::AdvAddRule [name] [description] [protocol] [direction] [status] [profile] [action] [application] [service_name] [icmp_types_and_codes] [group] [local_ports] [remote_ports] [local_address] [remote_address]
```